# Анимация изменения цвета для UILable

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день. Ребята я не могу разобраться в анимации смены цвета для UILable.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:6.0 animations:^{

     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     lblName.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

 }];
```

В этом коде, плавно, за 6 секунд я меняю фон, с любого цвета, на черный и он меняется плавно. Так же я написал о замене цвета для текста UILable и по логике она тоже должна плавно меняться.

Но по факту получается что UILable мгновенно меняет цвет. А фон постепенно.

Помогите разобраться с этой бедой!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойство `UIView` `backgroundColor` - анимируемое, то есть поддерживается его анимация в методе `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` ([UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), раздел Animations),

свойство `UILabel` `textColor` - не анимируемое, то есть вы так просто, всего лишь поместив изменение его значения в `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]`, не получите никакой анимации. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426614/how-to-animate-the-textcolor-property-of-an-uilabel) есть варианты как реализовать анимацию этого свойства используя другие подходы.

Answer (score 1):

Тема не раскрыта! Вы можете заменить UILabel самим собой только другого цвета. Выполните этот код и вы получите, то что хотели:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.myLabel
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]